# How can I remove a fireplace insert without damaging the surrounding wall?

Tags: fireplace

I have a fireplace (factory-built) that requires replacement. It is in an interial wall in the house. How do I detach the flue, detach the gas line and remove the existing fireplace? Is it possible to remove the fireplace from the wall through the living room, and is it possible to put a new fireplace in through the living room, or must I remove and replace the fireplace through the attic space?

(See my comment below)

From the attic, the fireplace looks like this:

[image: View of fireplace from attic]

From inside the living room, the fireplace resembles this:
[image]

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer without knowing the layout of the house. For example if the fireplace is in the bedroom on the second floor, and you want to move it to the living room 100' away on the first floor. as opposed to turning it around in the wall and having it open in the living room, rather than the bedroom on the other side of the wall.

Comment: Also a picture or model number of the fireplace would help.

Comment: Anything is possible, it's just a matter of what you're willing to spend.  Changing gas lines is not a DIY job. Not properly sealing the existing chimney can cause you many problems - leaks, mold, drafts. Not properly installing a (new) chimney can cause many problems - leaks, smoke backflow, buildup of material in the chimney over time which can cause fires. It is definitely a job you need permits for. Hard to give any better advice without pictures of existing fireplace/roof/chimney, and pictures/plans of where you want the new one to go (eg, how are you planning on routing new chimney?)

Comment: House is a Single Storey.

Fireplace is single-sided, and is in the living room, so, what I meant was to remove it from the alcove into the house, rather than lift it from the alcove into the attic.

What I am after is how to get the fireplace out and replace it without having to rip out a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to dismantle the mantle.  Seriously though, either way you remove it you are going to have to take apart the wall surrounding it. The fireplace insert should be attached to the framing around it, so you'll have to get to these attachment points to remove it.

[image]

Comment: And that pretty-much wraps it up for me... The only question now, is whether the open pit in the attic is okay or whether I need to bridge decking over the fireplace pit across the ceiling joists.

Comment: The 'pit' is a place for cold air to come in, so if that's a concern, it'd be nice to close it up some...though note that you typically can't have framing up to the chimney...check with your local codes before doing that.